# DateListPlot input entry problem

Tags: curated-data, data-structures

I imported some data from Excel and got the following for my date and values:

```
{{{1986, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0.}, 25.56, ""}, {{1986, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0.}, 26., ""}
```

It seems that there is an extra space there. How can I remove that and make appropriate format for `DateListPlot`? Also important: what materials do I need to learn to overcome such difficulties?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
l = {{{1986, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0.}, 25.56, ""}, {{1986, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0.},  26., ""}};
DateListPlot[l[[All, 1 ;; 2]], Joined -> True]
```

Take a look at `Span (;;)` and `Part ( [[ ]] )`

Answer (score 3):

Another option with `Most[]`:

```
l = {{{1986, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0.}, 25.56, ""}, {{1986, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0.},  26., ""}};
DateListPlot[Most/@l, Joined -> True]
```

> `Most[expr]`
>   gives expr with the last element removed.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `Transpose[]` with `Thread[]`:

```
l = {{{1986, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0.}, 25.56, ""}, {{1986, 1, 3, 0, 0, 0.},26., ""}};
DateListPlot[Thread[Transpose[l][[1 ;; 2]]], Joined -> True]
```